# Tyedef Struct Not Handling Non-Managed C++/CLI

Tags: struct, bitmap, c++-cli, typedef

I want to create a picture structure where some of the atributes will be the path to the picture and a bitmap of the picture. The issue is that when I add these atributes it underlines the variable name in red and says

```
A member of a non-managed class cannot be handled.
```

Is there some type of workaround for this? Here is my code:

```
typedef struct{
    System::String^ Path;
    BitMap^ image;

}Picture
```

I know I could use a char* for the path, but for other reasons I am choosing to use a `String^`.

Comment: How will you use this struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly embed a managed reference into a native type.

You wrap them into the gcroot template:

```
typedef struct{
    gcroot<System::String^> Path;
    gcroot<BitMap^> image;
}Picture
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your `typedef` declares a native struct (and why are you using `typedef struct` in C++ in the first place?  `struct Whatever` works just as well, but that's neither here nor there.)

```
ref struct MyStruct {}
```

Declares a managed `struct`, though it's not the same as a C# `struct`.  You can also use:

```
value struct MyStruct {}
// or
value class MyStruct {}
```

For a C# equivalent. The struct/class difference in a C++/CLI program are akin to C++ struct/class differences, not C# struct/class differences.  It's the `ref` and `value` modifiers that are important.